# Character doesn't show up and I also get this message: TypeError: invalid destination position for blit

Tags: python, pygame

Console:

```
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.16, Python 3.8.12)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 96, in <module>
    redrawGameWindow()
  File "main.py", line 23, in redrawGameWindow
    win.blit(walkLeft,[walkCount//3], (x,y))
TypeError: invalid destination position for blit
```

This is my code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500)) # Window height and width eg: Width,Height

pygame.display.set_caption("Wall-E trash collector") #Window name

#images
walkRight = pygame.image.load("nest/player/right.png")
walkLeft = pygame.image.load("nest/player/left.png")
walkUp = pygame.image.load("nest/player/up.png")
walkDown = pygame.image.load("nest/player/down.png")
bg = pygame.image.load("nest/background.png")

def redrawGameWindow():
    global walkCount
    
    win.blit(bg, (0,0))  # This will draw our background image at (0,0)    
    if walkCount + 1 >= 27:
        walkCount = 0
        
    if left:
        win.blit(walkLeft,[walkCount//3], (x,y))
        walkCount += 1                          
    elif right:
        win.blit(walkRight,[walkCount//3], (x,y))
        walkCount += 1
    else:
        walkCount = 0
        
    pygame.display.update() 
    



#game character height, width, start x and y, and speed.
x = 50
y = 50
width = 40
height = 40 
vel = 5 #speed of character

left = False
right = False
up = False
down = False
walkCount = 0

run = True
while run:
  pygame.time.delay(100)
  
  for event in pygame.event.get(): 
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT: #if player clicks exit button, ends program
      run = False #              <--^

  keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

  if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > vel:
    x -= vel
    left = True
    right = False
    up = False
    down = False
    
  elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 500 - width - vel:
    x += vel
    left = False
    right = True
    up = False
    down = False
    
  elif keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > vel:
    y -= vel
    left = False
    right = False
    up = True
    down = False
    
  elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y < 500 - height - vel:
    y += vel
    left = False
    right = False
    up = False
    down = True

  else: #If th character is not moving, it stays the same
    left = False
    right = False
    up = False
    down = False
    walkCount = 0

#-------------------------------------------------
  
  redrawGameWindow()
  
pygame.QUIT
```

I have been watching a Youtube tutorial to make my code for a little game I want to make and I have made it here and my code doesn't work when I try to move the character. The Character also doesn't show up. Could someone explain to me why this is happening and how to fix it? I don't know much about Python and Pygame

Comment: I now get this `TypeError: 'pygame.Surface' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: `walkRight` and `walkRight` are _Surface_ objects, but not a lists of _Surfaces_. You have just 1 image, but not a list of images. So just `win.blit(walkRight, (x,y))` and `win.blit(walkLeft, (x,y))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you said "TypeError: 'pygame.Surface' object is not subscriptable" this is a common error when you forgot to add the comma in (x,y). Hope this helps.

if you need more help go to: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/pygame.Surface%27+object+is+not+subscriptable